# Do/does - what to use with either?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, either-any

If you and two other people were in a room, and you needed to ask them for water, would you say to them "**Do** either of you have water?", or "**does** either of you have water?"?

Answer (score 1):

You would not say **either** but would ask

> Does any of you have water?

or

> Do any of you have water?

The word **either** is used with two.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "Does any of you have water?" is ungrammatical to at least some speakers. Though it might be used. "any" is normally considered plural. "Does anybody have water?" would be a possibility though.

Comment: I changed the number of people to two. 
I ask this question because I was pointed out  to that you don't use "does" in "Does either of you have water.", in its stead, you use "do". I was confused because I'd looked it up on the internet, and most sites i went on claimed they were both fine.

Comment: In quite the same way, I was told you don't say "Does any of you have water" either.

Comment: **I was pointed out to** is not a valid passive, at least not in AmE.  *It was pointed out to me that 'I was pointed out to' is not a valid passive.*

Comment: @DRF: How do you feel about **does any of them** ? Does that sound more grammatical to you than **does any of you**?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Ok interesting. "Does any of them," sounds on edge. I would say grammatical, though maybe clumsy. In that I would say it but would probably avoid it in writing. "Do any of them" and "Do any of you" both sound grammatical. Looking around it seems to be a common source of contention. I've gone through my copy of CGEL but there are way too many places "any" shows up. Will look again tomorrow.